# How do I make my code run all the way through?

Tags: sql, alter

What is it I need to do to make my code run all the way through please? It breaks on the ALTER TABLE parts where I add columns because it says they don't exist yet - do I have to put some sort of break in the code here? I'm a novice user but presume it is because of the order it is executing each step?

Example of a section of the code where it breaks - currently it only works if I run all my updates (there are more than shown here) and then run the Alter Table part separately afterwards.

```
update TABLE_2
set MEASURE = '-9'
where RESPONSE = '1' 
and QUESTION = '22d' and MEASURE not in (1,2)

update TABLE_2
set MEASURE = '-9'
where RESPONSE = '1' 
and QUESTION = '22e' and MEASURE not in (1,2)

update TABLE_2
set MEASURE = '-9'
where RESPONSE = '1' 
and QUESTION = '22f' and MEASURE not in (1,2)



--Create a ‘CONC’ column of La Code, Stratum and Question:

alter table TABLE_2
add [CONC] nvarchar(10)

update TABLE_2
set [CONC] = [LA_CODE] + [STRATUM_1] + [question]
where [CONC] is NULL
```

Comment: In SQL, you would just put GO after the lines you need executed. I'm not sure which database you're using because you didn't tag it.

Comment: SQL has no GO. Perhaps SQL Server has.

Comment: In some SQL flavors (like SQL Server) `GO` works like a semicolon.  Because we don't know which database, the OP just needs to add a `;` to the end of every statement.  Unless they are just missing from the code-snippet

Comment: The ';' worked perfectly thank you, that is all it needed! I'm new to SQL so didn't know if a BODMAS type thing applied to the code and the order it ran

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `go` as expressed in the comments.  I want to point out that the first three statements can be simplified to:

```
update TABLE_2
    set MEASURE = -9
where RESPONSE = 1 and
      QUESTION in ('22d', '22e', '22f')
      MEASURE not in (1, 2);
```

Then use `go`.

Combining the logic this way makes the code more maintainable and less prone to error.  I removed the single quotes on the constants for `RESPONSE` and `MEAUSRE` assuming they are some type of number.  If not, then use single quotes for all comparisons and assignments.